# Is there a way to find rebar in concrete walls?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, conduit

I was wondering if there is a way to find the tie rods and also plastic electrical conduit in concrete walls. In Ecuador all walls are made from poured concrete and plastic conduit is run. But it all tends to disappear. IS there some sort of xray way of finding the hidden PVC pipes, Tie rods and plastic conduit?

Answer (score 2):

X-ray? Sure they do this often in commercial buildings but it's probably well outside of something that is cost effective in a house.

A metal detector would locate the rebar and a tone generator could be used on a wire in the conduit in order to locate it.

Comment: Ultrasound would work nicely to find the air space that exists in the plastic pipe.

Comment: Have you had luck with a tone generator through a few inches of concrete?

Comment: Never tried @mazura.